# How to reproduce Google's floating/pinned live score?

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome

Trying to reproduce Google's pinned live score in Chrome as below with Javascript, but I can't find any documentation or examples about this; I can't believe this is a Google developers exclusive behavior, how can I achieve this?

[image: example]

https://www.androidpolice.com/2018/06/08/google-will-help-keep-track-2018-fifa-world-cup-action/

Comment: Its not, Facebook does something similar with chat heads.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481226/creating-a-system-overlay-window-always-on-top    It reuqires special permissions and runtime permissions.  Drag and drop is something you'd likely need to implement yourself.

Comment: If you can trigger such a behavior through Chrome, I guess you must be able to reproduce that via Javascript, can't you?
I updated my initial question to make it clearer that I'm looking for a front-end solution.

Comment: Mums I'd a front end solution. Java on android is front end. Youth's looking for JavaScript, which is a web based solution. You which I'd need to say I highly doubt it, unless you're talking react native

Comment: If you closely observe the notification of floating live score widget, you will find that it belongs to Google App, and not Chrome App. From chrome web page, you are just triggering Google App to launch the widget. Google has cleverly integrated chrome's google web page and it's Google App through cloud. And, as far as the widget is concerned, I strongly believe that its not JavaScript implementation rather Android-Java implementation. You can still look for Google's PIP documentation of Desktop Chrome Webpage.